# WPF autosize hight with a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a WPF window. When the user resize it, controls are following the window.
I'd like to do it also verticaly.
I'd like my datagrid get
Like in this video to explain the effect I want to do..
[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/WTB2OMf2yMU)

Comment: Please have a look at: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The question as it is now lacks debugging details and is of no use to others, especially with a YouTube link that might be gone tomorrow. That being said, most likely you are using a `StackPanel` with vertical orientation, which does not distribute the remaining space. Use a `Grid` or a `DockPanel` instead.

Comment: Oh, all right @thatguy. Thx for answering me and sorry for the procedure. Next time, I'll create a minimal reproductible example. Take care.

Comment: Do you have a .xaml code that is not working and you want to fix it? or you just want an example code that works like the one in the video? If you have tried some code that is not working so post it to allow the community to suggest you code-fixes